# Bot not pinging a member

Tags: discord.js

My Script:

```js
guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get("805423246370930708").send("Welcome! <@$[guildMember.user.id}> to our server! Make sure to check out the #Rules channel!");
```

The bot was supposed to ping the member who joins but instead, it literally says "<@$[guildMember.user.id}>"

Answer (score 2):

Replace your double quotes with backticks and square brackets with curly brackets. You must mention the `#Rules` channel as well.

Here is fixed version:

```js
guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get("805423246370930708").send(`Welcome! <@${guildMember.user.id}> to our server! Make sure to check out the <#RULES_CHANNEL_ID> channel!`);
```